# plt parameters not assigning to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below outputs a graph:

```
tableOfSubZeroSellsHH.plot(use_index=True, kind='bar', stacked=True,
                       title='figure', figsize=(14,7))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.ylabel('MW')
```

[image]

But when I go to add a second y axis line plot, it appears the above plt parameters dont assign to the figure:

```
tableOfSubZeroSellsHH.plot(use_index=True, kind='bar', stacked=True,
                           title='figure', figsize=(14,7))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.ylabel('MW')

ax = meteoFiltered['MeteoWindDA'].plot(secondary_y=True, style='--', color='black', linewidth=2.0)
ax.set_ylabel('MeteoWind')
```

[image]

It seems plt.xticks does not rotate the xlables and the y axis grid lines do not appear. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: See if moving the 2 ax.-- lines to before `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` helps

Comment: @Redox I moved the ax variable above plt.xticks, upon executing the script this brought in the y gridlines, but still no rotation on the xticks. Very strange.

Comment: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)`, which needs to be called later than `ax = meteoFiltered['MeteoWindDA'].plot(...)`

Comment: @JohanC still to no avail unfortunately. I included your suggestion after `ax = meteoFiltered['MeteoWindDA'].plot(...)` and it still didnt work

Comment: Ah, you have a `secondary_y`, which complicates matters (internally, matplotlib implements this as two subplots on top of each other). If you'd add reproducible test data, it would be easier for people to solve your problem.